# How to define a 0..1 to many relationship in code-first

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-relationship

I'm reading ado.net team blog's articles these days, when I find how to create one to one relationship, one to many relationship and many to many relationship. But, is there a way to create 0..1 to many relationship?

```
class TestA
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] stamp { get; set; }       
    public TestB TB { get; set; }
}

class TestB
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] stamp { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TestA> TA { get; set; }
}

class myContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TestA> players { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TestB> teams { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TestB>().HasOptional<TestA>(a => a);
    }
}
```

Thx inadvance!

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi @leppie, I have edited the post, but it throws an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Try mapping it as follows.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<TestA>().HasOptional(a => a.TB)
       .WithMany(b => b.TA);
}
```

Articles on mapping

- [Associations in EF Code First: Part 6 – Many-valued Associations](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/17/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-6-many-valued-associations.aspx)
  Other parts of this series are also very good
- [Entity Framework 4.1 Code First (With One to Many relationship) Code
  Example](http://codeblog.shawson.co.uk/entity-framework-4-1-code-first-with-one-to-many-relationship-code-example/)
- [Code First Relationships Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698)

Comment: Hi @Eranga, you told me how to get it, but I still don't know why should I write that. Could you please provide me some information about create relationship between entities, any helpful links are OK. Thanks in advance!